# Calculate (three wheeled) mobile robot position and heading

Tags: trigonometry, kinematics

I've tried to use odometry data (distance (dist) and steering angle ($\alpha$) from front wheel of mobile robot to calculate position of rear wheels using following:

[tricycle model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oDVD.jpg)

$\beta = dist / d * \tan (\alpha)$
($\beta$ = turning angle)

$R = \frac {dist} {\beta} $

$R.x = x - \sin(\theta) * R$

$R.y = y + cos(\theta) * R$

$\theta' = (\theta + \beta) \mod  2\pi$

$x' = R.x + sin(\theta') * R$

$y' = R.y - cos(\theta') * R$

It calculates $\theta'$ well with small steering angles, but it looks as $\theta'$ gets much too big when steering angle gets bigger than somewhere around $\frac {\pi} {3}$

Comment: the only model one can predict using just mathematics says that radii from the center of rotation meet the points where the wheels meet the floor parallel to the wheel axles. This becomes false, for example, if the two rear wheels cannot rotate independently; many children's tricycles put both on a common axle. If the rear wheels can rotate independently, you still expect problems based on friction, as the tread where each wheel meets the floor is not really infinitely thin.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it is good enough to approximate  with a bicycle model. Imagine a fictitious rear wheel placed midway along the rear axle of the tricycle. Then you have created a vehicle that resembles  a bike.  The front wheel of the vehicle can pivot freely,  but the  rear wheel axis is aligned rigidly with the body axis of the moving vehicle.

Here is a solution to the bike problem.

Denote the position vectors of the front and rear hubs of  the bike by $ F(t)$ and $R(t)$. Then the distance between these hubs is a fixed constant length  $L$. The  body axis of the vehicle  points in the direction of the displacement vector from $R$ to $F$. Its compass bearing is described by some angle $\theta(t)$,  hence the displacement vector can be written as 
$ F-R= \vec {RF} = L\vec u= L<\cos (\theta), \sin(\theta)>$.  Using complex exponential notation for the last expression we obtain

$F- R= L e^{i\theta}$. By differentiating $$(1) \qquad  F(t)- R(t) = L e^{ i \theta(t)}$$ you deduce that $$ (2) \qquad  \dot F - \dot R = L i \dot \theta e^{i \theta}  $$
But the rear wheel must travel in the same direction as the body axis $\vec u$ because it is aligned rigidly with the body frame. Thus the rear velocity vector is $(3 A) \qquad \dot R= C \vec u$ where $C$ is the speed of the rear wheel. The front wheel velocity vector is aligned with the direction that the front wheel is turned, which depends on the steering angle. Thus $ (3B) \qquad \dot F= k e^{i (\theta +\alpha)}$  where $k$ is the speed of the front wheel and $ \alpha$ is the steering angle, measured relative to the body axis vector $\vec u$.  Inserting (3)  into (2) and canceling $e^{i \theta}$ across all terms one deduces $$(4) \qquad k e^{i\alpha} = c+ i L \dot \theta$$ Interpreting the left and right sides of (4) as  the polar and  Cartesian forms of the same complex quantity, we deduce

$$(5A)\qquad k \cos \alpha= c$$ and $$(5B) \qquad  k\sin \alpha = L\dot \theta$$

Your data provides knowledge of $k$  (speed of front wheel) and $\alpha$ (steering angle relative to body frame axis). Thus you can use (5) to deduce the speed $c$ of the rear wheel and the rate of turning of the body  $\dot \theta= k \sin \alpha /L$.
By integrating both equations you can find the distance traveled by the rear wheel and the bearing of the body $\theta$. Then integrating the velocity vector  of the rear wheel $\dot R= c(t) e^{i \theta(t)}$ you can solve for the position of the rear wheel: $ R(t)= \int   c(t) e^{i \theta(t)} \ dt$

The analysis above assumes that there is no slipping. Note that this analysis predicts that the rear speed $c$ is always smaller than the front speed $k$, and therefore the rear wheel will always travel fewer miles than the front.